# Scrapy: store data with part in a nested tag in one item field

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I've got the following problem: I'm scraping prices from a website and it works but it only takes the numbers in front of the comma.

Example: when something is worth "€ 79,<sup>90</sup>" it will only scrape the 79, and not the 90.

```
<span class="price right right10">
    € 79,
    <sup>
    90*
    </sup>
</span>
```

I want to store this in one item field like this:

```
class Prices(scrapy.Item):
    price = scrapy.Field()
```

This is my current xpath selector:

```
item['price'] = ''.join(sel.xpath('div[@class="waresSum"]/p/span/text()').extract())
```

Answer (score 3):

The key problem is that you are asking for direct text child nodes of the `span`, you need to get all the text nodes from the inside of the `span` element:

```
//div[@class="waresSum"]/p/span//text()
                            HERE^
```

Also, I would use [`.re()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.re) to filter out unwanted characters and get only digits, `,` and `-`:

```
$ scrapy shell index.html
In [9]: ''.join(response.xpath('//span//text()').re(r'[0-9,\-]+'))
Out[9]: u'79,90'
```